# JavaScript - How to print PDF manually?

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing

In my application I have a pdf displayed in an `<object>` tag
like this.
Below the pdf I have a print button. How can I print the pdf when the button is clicked. ?

```
<object data="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQNCiX15Pb8DQoNCjkgMCBvYmoNCjw8....
<button onclick="printPdf()">Print</button>
```

I tried using window.print, but it is printing the entire page and not the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I print the pdf when the button is clicked. ?

You can't... at least not when you are displaying the PDF using the object tag.

When you use the object tag, you are relying on the OS level pdf viewer or the viewer built into the browser to display the PDF. Different viewers and different browsers have different APIs... or none at all. There is no consistent method to trigger a print that will work across the various OS/Browser/Device combinations that are available.

You might look into this though. http://printjs.crabbly.com/

It claims it can print PDF without a viewer. You'd still be able to display the PDF using the object tag but have the print button elsewhere on the page.